# Selecting rows from a pandas dataframe based on the values of some columns in a list of the same dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's suppose, there is a dataframe :

```
df1 = 
   A  B   C
0  1  a  a1
1  2  b  b2
2  3  c  c3
3  4  d  d4
4  5  e  e5
5  6  f  f6
```

Created as :

```
a1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
a2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
a3 = ['a1','b2','c3','d4','e5','f6']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a1,a2,a3)),columns=["A","B","C"])
```

Here, I am considering Columns **A** and **B** to be something like primary keys for this dataframe.
So, `PK = ["A","B"]`.

I have another list, `list1 = [[2,'b'],[5,'e']]`, which is a subset of the dataframe `df[PK]`.

Is there any way I can get the rows corresponding to these primary key values inside the list from the dataframe df?

Something like :
`df1 = df[df[PK].values.isin(list1)]` which doesn't work as I expect.

I would like to get an output df1 as :

```
df1 =
   A  B   C
1  2  b  b2
4  5  e  e5
```

There are some similar questions, which I have gone through in this portal. But none of them showed me how to select rows based on filter on multiple columns as mentioned above.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use merge something like this `df1.merge(pd.DataFrame(list1,columns=PK),on=PK)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
import pandas as pd
a1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
a2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
a3 = ['a1','b2','c3','d4','e5','f6']

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a1,a2,a3)),columns=["A","B","C"])

PK = ["A","B"]

list1 = [[2,'b'],[5,'e']]

df2 = df1.merge(pd.DataFrame(list1,columns=PK),on=PK)

print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   A  B   C
0  2  b  b2
1  5  e  e5
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)